# How to filter Spark dataframe by array column containing any of the values of some other dataframe/set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe A that contains a column of array string.

```
...
 |-- browse: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
...
```

For example three sample rows would be

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| column 1|  browse| column n|
+---------+--------+---------+
|     foo1| [X,Y,Z]|     bar1|
|     foo2|   [K,L]|     bar2|
|     foo3|     [M]|     bar3|
```

And another Dataframe B that contains a column of string

```
|-- browsenodeid: string (nullable = true)
```

Some sample rows for it would be

```
+------------+
|browsenodeid|
+------------+
|           A|
|           Z|
|           M|
```

How can I filter A so that I keep all the rows whose `browse` contains any of the the values of `browsenodeid` from B? In terms of the above examples the result will be:

```
+---------+--=-----+---------+
| column 1|  browse| column n|
+---------+--------+---------+
|     foo1| [X,Y,Z]|     bar1| <- because Z is a value of B.browsenodeid
|     foo3|     [M]|     bar3| <- because M is a value of B.browsenodeid
```

If I had a single value then I would use something like

```
A.filter(array_contains(A("browse"), single_value))
```

But what do I do with a list or DataFrame of values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an elegant solution for this, without the need to cast `DataFrame`s/`Dataset`s to `RDD`s.

Assuming you have a DataFrame `dataDF`:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| column 1|  browse| column n|
+---------+--------+---------+
|     foo1| [X,Y,Z]|     bar1|
|     foo2|   [K,L]|     bar2|
|     foo3|     [M]|     bar3|
```

and an array `b` containing the values you want to match in `browse`

```
val b: Array[String] = Array(M,Z)
```

Implement the udf:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

def array_contains_any(s:Seq[String]): UserDefinedFunction = {
udf((c: WrappedArray[String]) =>
  c.toList.intersect(s).nonEmpty)
}
```

and then simply use the `filter` or `where` function (with a little bit of fancy currying :P) to do the filtering like:

```
dataDF.where(array_contains_any(b)($"browse"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spark >= 2.4.0 you can use [`arrays_overlap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_overlap):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, arrays_overlap, lit}

val df = Seq(
  ("foo1", Seq("X", "Y", "Z"), "bar1"),
  ("foo2", Seq("K", "L"), "bar2"),
  ("foo3", Seq("M"), "bar3")
).toDF("col1", "browse", "coln")

val b = Seq("M" ,"Z") 
val searchArray = array(b.map{lit}:_*) // cast to lit(i) then create Spark array

df.where(arrays_overlap($"browse", searchArray)).show()

// +----+---------+----+
// |col1|   browse|coln|
// +----+---------+----+
// |foo1|[X, Y, Z]|bar1|
// |foo3|      [M]|bar3|
// +----+---------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume input data:Dataframe A

```
browse
200,300,889,767,9908,7768,9090
300,400,223,4456,3214,6675,333
234,567,890
123,445,667,887
```

and you have to match it with Dataframe B

browsenodeid:(I flatten the column browsenodeid) 123,200,300

```
val matchSet = "123,200,300".split(",").toSet
val rawrdd = sc.textFile("D:\\Dataframe_A.txt")
rawrdd.map(_.split("|"))
      .map(arr => arr(0).split(",").toSet.intersect(matchSet).mkString(","))
      .foreach(println)
```

Your output:

```
300,200
300
123
```

**Updated**

```
val matchSet = "A,Z,M".split(",").toSet

val rawrdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/mvv45x9f1494518792828/input_A.txt")

rawrdd.map(_.split("|"))
      .map(r => if (! r(1).split(",").toSet.intersect(matchSet).isEmpty) org.apache.spark.sql.Row(r(0),r(1), r(2))).collect.foreach(println)
```

Output is

```
foo1,X,Y,Z,bar1
foo3,M,bar3
```

Comment: Manish thanks for your response but this is not quite what I am looking for. I have added some examples in the description to clarify what I have and what I want to achieve

Comment: Manish thanks for your answer. I wanted a solution that could be just plugged in to the `Dataset`'s `filter`/`where` functions so that it is more readable and more easily integrated to the existing codebase (mostly written around `DataFrame`s rather than `RDD`s). Check my answer above and if you like it upvote it for me!