# How to filter a spark's dataframe array with scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm a beginner with Scala.

I've got a dataframe with 2 columns :

the first is a date, the second an array of words.

```
created_at:string
words:array
    element:string
```

I wish to keep only words begining with a '#'

I would prefer to make the filter before exploding the array, as most words do not start with a '#'

I didn't find a way to modify an array column and apply something like a filter(_.startsWith("#")).

Is it possible ? and how ?

Thank's

Pierre

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904622/how-to-filter-spark-dataframe-by-array-column-containing-any-of-the-values-of-so?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple UDF to filter out the unwanted words from your array column:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2018-05-01", Seq("a", "#b", "c")),
  ("2018-05-02", Seq("#d", "#e", "f"))
).toDF("created_at", "words")

def filterArray = udf( (s: Seq[String]) =>
  s.filterNot(_.startsWith("#"))
)

df.select($"created_at", filterArray($"words")).show
// +----------+----------+
// |created_at|UDF(words)|
// +----------+----------+
// |2018-05-01|    [a, c]|
// |2018-05-02|       [f]|
// +----------+----------+
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.select(explode(col("words")).as("word"), col("created_at")).
       where("word LIKE '#%'").
       groupBy(col("created_at")).
       agg(collect_set(col("word")).as("words")).
       show
```

Comment: It should work, but it explode the array first. I wanted to avoid it. Still a good example of code, thanks